# Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactoryBean' defined in ServletContext resource

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'employeeService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'employeeDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactoryBean' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/tryMVCServlet-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/MetadataProvider

I tried to run application but getting error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.